# How to update an array of turtles based on input from ROS callback function

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, callback, updates, ros

I have a ROS node, which is subscribed to a topic in which several agents publish their positions and respective id. I want to be able to draw such agents as turtles and update their positions accordingly.

I have the following:

```python
class Visualizer():

def __init__(self):
    self.turtles = list()
    #Of the form: [[id, pos], ...]
    #[[1, [2, 3]],[2, [6, 7]],[3, [1, 1]],[4, [9, 8]], ...]
    self.logistics = []
    self.colors = []

    rospy.init_node('visualizer', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber('/environment/agent_position', Protocol_Msg, self.draw_agents)

    turtle.Screen()

def is_it_new(self, data):

    ----> check if broadcast received by new agent

    if new:
        self.turtles.append(turtle.Turtle())
        self.colors.append([random.random(), random.random(), random.random()])
        print self.colors
        self.logistics.append([turtle_id, pos])

    else:
        #only update position
        for x in self.logistics:
            if x[0] == turtle_id:
                x[1] = pos
    print self.logistics

def draw_agents(self, data):
    rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + "I heard %s", data.content)
    self.is_it_new(data)
    for x in self.logistics:
        if x[0] == int(data.sender):
            turtles[self.logistics.index(x)].setx(x[1][0])
            turtles[self.logistics.index(x)].sety(x[1][1])


if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        visualize = Visualizer()
        rospy.spin()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
    pass
```

However, this does not as I except and produces a

> RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop

I am not sure how to rewrite the code so that the update occurs in the main thread. (I haven't worked with such GUIs before).

Comment: Please add a bit more context to your code, preferably make it a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Right now, for example, it is unclear to me where the variable `turtle` comes from. Please also add where exactly the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the effort. I managed to solve it in the following way.
In the callback function, I put the new data in a Queue() like so:

```
    def __init__(self):
        .....
        self.turtle_queue = Queue.Queue()

    def put2queue(self, data):
        self.turtle_queue.put(data)
```

Then I call the drawing function from main like so:

```
if __name__=='__main__':

try:
    visualize = Visualizer()
    while True:
        data = visualize.turtle_queue.get()
        visualize.draw_agents(data)
except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
    traceback.print_exc()
    raise
```

So the gui is not updated from the callback thread, but from the main thread. :)